# Java Integer.parseInt vs Dart int.parse

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm familiar with Java's Class methods

```
      int x = Integer.parseInt("9");
```

in dart (which I'm new to) it's kinda weird that the method is called with the primitive type

```
      var x = int.parse('9');
```

any explanation, Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Dart everything (including primitives) is an object, so has methods. There's no need for the artificial boxing class `Integer` since `int` is already a class and can host the static string parsing method.